# Receiving data using DatagramSocket and connecting to a BluetoothSocket concurrently

Tags: java, android, sockets, bluetooth, udp

I am creating an Android App using minSDK version 7, targeting version 16 and am testing on a physical Galaxy Nexus device.  I'm trying to connect to a bluetooth device using the code displayed below under "Bluetooth device connection", which is run on its own thread periodically until there is a successful connection with the device.  On a separate thread, I am receiving UDP packets with the code displayed below under "UDP packet receiving".

While the bluetooth device is trying to connect, UDP packets are not received, but upon a successful connection to the bluetooth device the UDP packets start coming in.  The problem is I want the UDP packets to continue to stream even while the bluetooth device is trying to connect but I can't find why the packets aren't being received while the device is trying to connect.

These are the permissions I have set:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"></uses-permission>
```

Bluetooth device connection:

```
    public void run() {
        synchronized (BluetoothSocketService.this) {
            if (mState != HeadsetConnectionState.CONNECTED) {
                Log.i(TAG, "BEGIN mConnectThread");

                BluetoothSocket tmp = null;
                try {
                    tmp = mmDevice
                            .createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(MY_UUID);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "create() failed", e);
                }
                mmSocket = tmp;
                mAdapter.cancelDiscovery();

                try {
                    mmSocket.connect();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    try {
                        mmSocket.close();
                    } catch (IOException e2) {
                        Log.e(TAG,
                                "unable to close() socket during connection failure",
                                e2);
                    }
                    Log.d(TAG, "bluetooth failed to connect");
                    if (connectTimer != null)
                        connectTimer.schedule(
                                new ConnectTimerTask(mmDevice),
                                DELAY_BEFORE_RECONNECT_ATTEMPT_MS,
                                TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
                    return;
                }
                connected(mmSocket, mmDevice);
            }
        }
    }
```

UDP packet receiving:

```
public void run() {
    if (_myDatagramSocket != null) {
        if (isRunning) {
            Logger.printProcess("UdpServer.run()",
                    "UdpServer is running @ " + _myPort);
        }
    } else {
        Logger.printError("UdpServer.run()",
                "Socket is null. closing UdpServer.");
        return;
    }

    while (isRunning) {
        try {
            byte[] myBuffer = new byte[_myDatagramSize];
            DatagramPacket myPacket = new DatagramPacket(myBuffer,
                    _myDatagramSize);
            System.out.println("Receiving datagram packet!");
            _myDatagramSocket.receive(myPacket);
            _myListener.process(myPacket, _myPort);
        } catch (IOException ioex) {
            Logger.printProcess("UdpServer.run()", " socket closed.");
            break;
        } catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException ex) {
            Logger.printError("UdpServer.run()",
                    "ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException:  " + ex);
        }
    }
    dispose();
}
```

Comment: When you get an exception, don't just log a message of your own devising. Log the one that comes with the exception. For example you can't just assume that an IOException when receiving means that the socket is closed. And log the message *before* doing anything else such as trying to close the socket. Fix your code and re-test.

Comment: I made the change of logging before closing the socket, but my original problem persists.  Do you have any other suggestions about why bluetooth might be blocking UDP packet sending?

I also tried to make the "DELAY_BEFORE_RECONNECT_ATTEMPT_MS" value large and I can see that the UDP packets are sent and received in between reconnection attempts.